# Is there a standard on number of Ignite caches per cluster?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I know that more number of caches open too many file descriptors and consume more resources.

1. Is there a recommendation on number of caches per ignite/GridGain cluster?
2. Is there a recommendation on number of caches vs number of nodes vs OS configuration (CPU, RAM)

We have 45 caches (PARTITIONED) and the system configuration is 4 CPU and 60GB RAM on each node. It is a 3 node cluster.

Current data storage size is 2GB and Data is expected to grow 1.5-2 TB in next one year.

We are frequently getting "Too many open files" error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there's nothing wrong with increasing the limit for file descriptors on the OS level. You can use the `ulimit` utility for that.

Another option is to leverage [cache groups](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/configuring-caches/cache-groups#cache-groups), it will make caches share some structures including files.